# I need to detect the set of weeks and set of months in given list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I need to find out the number of days ,weeks and months included in the given set of lists

```
l1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,31]
one week i.e [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
one day i.e [8]
one month and a day i.e [1-30,31]
```

ive done trying using consecutive lists and many which didnt provide any help to me

Comment: What would the output for `l1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` be?

Comment: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and 8,9

Comment: Just that... no days at all ?

Comment: the days would be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Comment: since a week is possible [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and two days are [8,9]

Comment: Why in your example is a month and a day there... is it presuming a month is always 30 days? Because it could well be that `1 - 31` is a month and no days? You'd have more luck getting this answered if 1) You include your attempt (even if it didn't work) so far and 2) Flesh out the exact grouping logic...

Comment: As well as the query above... Why isn't 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 also two weeks as 2-8 is a week? If you could clarify the exact logic and show your current attempt that'd be great. Thanks.

Comment: i would be grateful to send you the whole question if you are willing to solve it

Comment: That's not how this site works... if you can make an [edit] to include what I've mentioned about the logic and the code you've tried that doesn't work and ask a clearly defined question regarding what the exact issue is you're facing - then someone can help... I'm afraid SO isn't a "solve this task for me" site...

Comment: This looks like it might be similar to the roman numerals problem.